# Failing to inject a view with ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm following the MEAN stack tutorial on Thinkster, and I've run into a couple of problems.

The first was with inline views, using a script tag with the id equal to "home.html", for example, which should have then been routed to using ui router. This didn't work, but I fixed the issue by creating separate files containing whatever markup I wanted between the script tags.

Now I'm moving into the realm of node and express, and hosting a local server. I'm also trying to follow the basic node structure. I have an app.js file in the root of my project, and the code from the tutorial in angularApp.js, which is contained in public/javascripts. I've moved my views into the views folder.

This is the structure:

```
Root --- app.js
     |
     --- views  --- index.ejs, home.html, posts.html
     |
     --- public --- javascripts --- angularApp.js
```

When the app starts, it first finds angularApp.js (good), but then fails to load home.html. Nothing is displayed (the screen is blank).

This is my **angularApp.js** app.config section:

```
    app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('/posts', {
          url: 'posts/{id}',
          templateUrl: 'posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/views/home');
    }]);
```

This is my **home.html**:

```
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
    ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
    {{post.upvotes}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      <!-- If the link is supplied, make it the href -->
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">{{post.title}}</a>
      <!-- If the link isn't supplied, just display the title -->
      <span ng-hide="post.link">{{post.title}}</span>
      <span>
        <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
      </span>
      - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    </span>

  </div>

  <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new post</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
  </form>
```

I think the issue is with my treatment of the parameters to ui router - I feel like I've tried every combination and I'm at my wits end. A link to the whole codebase is here: https://github.com/Zombiefruit/mean_test_01. I just want the view to inject!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web root is `public`, so you'll have to create a folder `views` inside public then move `home.html` and `posts.html` into it.

And then changing `templateUrl` to `'/views/home.html'` would work.

Btw the otherwise route should be `/home`

Comment: This fixed it! Did you manage to get the comments working (if by any chance you cloned the repo)?

Comment: Er... you mean the route part or? I don't have `mongodb` setup so I can't really test. But if I remove DB part I can access the `posts` route

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the relative path to the templateUrl like templateUrl: '/views/home.html'.

Edit: The ID parameter should be set using :id instead of {id}. Sorry, I didn't notice that before. :)

Comment: I've tried that, I end up getting the same result. I've also tried using every combination of the router prover .otherwise() path. Some will cause a 404 error, some will simply do nothing. Sadly, none will work (that I've tried).

Comment: Replace the {Id} with :id

Comment: That didn't fix it, unfortunately. The injection of posts.html isn't too important right now, as home.html is the parent. I'd be happy with just getting a header to show up.

Comment: What console errors are you getting (if any)? If you're using a minified Angular or angular-UI-router, the console errors will look like gibberish. Use nonminified to get better logs.

Comment: Zero console errors. In the terminal for the node server I'll get a stream of 404 errors if the parameters to app.config are a certain format, and a simple "GET /javascripts/angularApp.js" which succeeds when I'm not getting 404s. Neither situations result in the rendering of a view.

Comment: If you're serving this from Node and Express, ensure you've a static route setup for serving files. If angular handles all of your routing, have express use a universal route to your main file (index.html), within which you'll have your ui-view, etc. With that said, we'd need to see your server side setup to know how express is handling things on the backend. I'm relatively inexperienced with Stackoverflow as a community, so the mods may request you open a new thread with all of this new information.